# Use wildcard searches in jsonb postgres

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I need to perform wild card searches for fields nested at a deeper level in a jsonb structure through postgres. I know how to query for exact matches but I need to do partial matches as well. Below is the json schema.

Table name- employee

```
json_data={
"data":[    
        {“a”:"Amit",”b”: [ { “val”: "India"} ] },  

        {“a”:"Akash",”b”: [ { “val”: "Indonesia"} ] }

      ]}


select json_data 
from employee 
where json_data @> '"data":[{"b":[{"val":"India"}]}]';
```

I need to do searches for all values of `b:[{val:%Ind}]` in all the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those nested arrays inside the structure really make searching hard. As a result of that you need to unnest the structure twice so that you can access the individual values.

```
select e.*
from employee e
where exists (select * 
              from jsonb_array_elements(e.json_data #> '{data}') as x1(data)
                cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(x1.data -> 'b') as x2(b)
              where x2.b ->> 'val' like 'Ind%');
```

The `jsonb_array_elements()` call returns all array elements of the top-level array as rows. For each row, all key/value pairs at the key `'b'` are extracted as rows again. That result can then be searched for with a `LIKE` condition.

Online example: https://rextester.com/FCUJU88109

You can see what the sub-select does by running:

```
select e.id, x1.data, x2.b
from employee e
     cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(e.json_data #> '{data}') as x1(data)
     cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(x1.data -> 'b') as x2(b);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did help me a lot .